# Using multiple domain names on same server

Tags: domain, web-hosting

I'm developing a website where users will be able to aggregate their RSS feeds and create custom pages. I want to give each user separate domain name like jonhdoe.com, xyz.org. I'll be keeping files on single server in one web application (I don't want to replace all the api for all users).

Now the question: How can I make multiple domain names point to single web site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy, if you just create DNS entries for each domain to point to the same server VIP/IP then the request will go there - how you then deal with these differing domain requests comes down to what web-server combo you're using and any router/load-balancer configs you choose to create but it all starts with getting DNS right.

That said you could get into a bit of bother if you have LOTS of users as you'll need to buy (if available) all those domains. It might be better to have johndoe.somethingselse.com - that way all traffic goes to somethingelse.com and your servers then map the johndoe bit to your functionality - in fact I'd strongly recommend you do this.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using custom setup dns server to answer all queries with single same answer which point to single same server:
http://it.dennyhalim.com/2009/11/park-and-monetize-idle-domains.html

so, all i need is setup new domain using my dns and all will point to my server.